# How to generate Dynamic request header in Python?

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I am new on python. I am sending POST Request using this line of code:

```
response = requests.post(url=API_ENDPOINT, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

The problem is that the values of header are dynamic(they are different every time on browser).
These are the headers in browser:

```
headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "276",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Cookie": "acceptedCookie=%7B%22type%22%3A%22all%22%7D; TS01a14d32=01f893c9654ba8a49f70366efc3464fd76d4a461343cf44a7f074a5071b9818b6b196051effd669b784f691c8fab79bdc5a7efada418db04fc3cf8c3e43224fe186e64941eab43b5d9500201644abda7c0f5914ebb9ab95046ee2cb83c43f259ab0ed0e538fee3db50b2aa541ee5646d70634cea4cec54352547d3366c51e2ae5270756ee57bf78d915dcb8209c9c5771956c715bd75fb761bf42da6ba5cfa34ffbfee670e871ed33f8e25c09fdfc882953efd981f; ASLBSA=85b54f44c65f329c72b20a3ee7a9fc9a63d44001bc2c4e2c2b2f26fdaba7e0e3; ASLBSACORS=85b54f44c65f329c72b20a3ee7a9fc9a63d44001bc2c4e2c2b2f26fdaba7e0e3; utag_main=v_id:0179ddda773b0020fa6584d13ce40004e024f00d00978$_sn:2$_ss:1$_st:1623016566769$_pn:1%3Bexp-session$ses_id:1623014766769%3Bexp-session; s_cc=true; s_fid=3BE425806C624053-0396695F1870C86E; s_sq=luxmyluxottica%3D%2526pid%253DSite%25253APreLogin%25253ALogin%2526pidt%253D1%2526oid%253DLOGIN%2526oidt%253D3%2526ot%253DSUBMIT; todayVisit=true",
    "Host": "mywebsite.com",
    "Origin": "https://mywebsite.com",
    "Referer": "https://mywebsite.com",
    "TE": "Trailers",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
    }
```

The value of content length, cookies, Accept parameter is different every time whenever I hit the API on browser, so I cannot just copy paste the values of headers and send it on POST request. How to generate this dynamic header(how to generate content length, cookies etc)? Please help.

Comment: mainly `cookies` which is changing, try to find which cookie is changing or you can simply  requests the first page   save cookie for  that pass on other requests like save first page 
 cookie `cookies = response.cookies`  pass to other `requests.get(cookies=cookies)`

Comment: And how to generate page content? It also keeps on changing

Comment: page content will be fix. can you explain more how content will be changing .

Comment: Sometimes the value of content Length is 404, sometimes it's 276. It's not fixed. Although the data I pass is same. Don't know on which basis the value of content Length changes.